# Como saber que botão foi clicado?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho três botões, um para *inserir*, outro para *alterar* e um para *gravar*.

O botão de *gravar* vai funcionar para salvar dados tanto se for de uma inserção ou uma alteração.

Como identificar qual botão eu carreguei para o botão *Gravar* saber se estou a gravar uma inserção ou uma alteração?

```
private void button_inserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = "Inserir dados";

    textBox_ordenado.ReadOnly = false;
    textBox_ordenado.Enabled = true;
    textBox_ordenado.Focus();

    textBox_subsidios.ReadOnly = false;
    textBox_subsidios.Enabled = true;
    textBox_subsidios.TabStop = true;

    dateTimePicker_data.Enabled = true;
    button_guardar.Visible = true;
}

private void button_alterar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = "Alterar dados";

    textBox_ordenado.ReadOnly = false;
    textBox_ordenado.Enabled = true;
    textBox_ordenado.Focus();

    textBox_subsidios.ReadOnly = false;
    textBox_subsidios.Enabled = true;
    textBox_subsidios.TabStop = true;

    dateTimePicker_data.Enabled = true;
    button_guardar.Visible = true;
}

private void button_guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button_inserir) // Não sei como fazer
    {
        // executa uma stored Procedure (inserir)
    }
    else if (button_alterar) // Não sei como fazer
    {
        // executa outra stored Procedure (alterar)
    }       
}
```

Comment: que tal? `if(this.Text == "Inserir dados")` `else if(this.Text == "Alterar dados")`

Comment: Consegui dessa forma @Marconi muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Que bom que pude te ajudar @Diogo.

Comment: @Marconi Por que não posta uma resposta?

Comment: @zekk nem precisa a sua já está bem completa.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso vai depender de como o botão *Gravar* é invocado, se você chamá-lo assim:

```
private void button_inserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    button_guardar_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Você pode saber quem invocou o botão desse jeito:

```
private void button_guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button btn = sender as Button;
   MessageBox.Show(btn.Name); // button_inserir

   // if (btn.Name == "button_inserir") { }
}
```

Outra forma é usar uma variável para guardar um valor quando um dos botões for clicado, no botão *Guardar* você verifica o valor da variável e executa os procedimentos de acordo com o método escolhido.

```
// 0: Nenhum botão clicado / 1: botão inserir clicado / 2: botão alterar clicado
static int metodoGuardar = 0; 
// ...

private void button_inserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Códigos aqui...
   metodoGuardar = 1;
}

private void button_alterar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Códigos aqui...
   metodoGuardar = 2
}

private void button_guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (metodoGuardar == 1)
   {
      // Botão "inserir" foi clicado
   } else if (metodoGuardar == 2)
   {
      // Botão "alterar" foi clicado
   } else
   {
      // Nenhum dos botões "inserir" e "alterar" foram clicados
   }
}
```

Relacionado: [Pegar informações do objeto `sender`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Não consegui dessa forma @zekk ... Não aconteceu nada

Comment: @DiogoSousa Complementei a resposta, veja se a outra forma também pode ser aplicada no teu caso.

Comment: Muito obrigado @zekk consegui usando a variável, não consegui chamando o botão... acho q tenho de ver melhor como funciona o sender e o EventArgs. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Boa noite, @Diogo Sousa.

Eu utilizo constantes e através delas verifico dentro do botão Gravar ou Efetiva se é um comando INSERT ou UPDATE.

Também utilizo uma propriedade que é carregada com o conteúdo da constante quando botão é clicado;

Exemplos:

```
// Constantes
private const string strConstInseri = "Inseri";
private const string strConstAltera = "Altera";
private const string strConstCancela = "Cancela";
private const string strConstConsulta = "Consulta";
private const string strConstEfetiva = "Efetiva";

// Atributos
private static string strTextBotao;

// Propriedade é utilizada para, manipular a propriedade "Text" dos botões
public static string StrTextBotao
{
    get { return strTextBotao; }
    private set { strTextBotao = value; }
}

// Botão Inseri
private void btnInseri_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtCodInstrucao.Clear();
    txtConteudo.Clear();

    // É setado um valor na propriedade e esse valor será utilizado para distinguir as operações na hora de efetivar no evento click do "botão - Efetiva"
    StrTextBotao = strConstInseri;

    HabDes(StrTextBotao);
}

// Botão Altera
private void btnAltera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvCodRejeicao.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (dgvCodRejeicao.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            txtCodInstrucao.Text = dgvCodRejeicao["colCodInstrucao", dgvCodRejeicao.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            txtConteudo.Text = dgvCodRejeicao["colConteudo", dgvCodRejeicao.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();

            StrTextBotao = strConstAltera;

            HabDes(StrTextBotao);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selecione um registro na tabela para fazer a alteração.", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        return;
    }
}

// Botão Efetiva
private void btnEfetiva_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    #region INSERI

    if (StrTextBotao == strConstInseri)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente inserir um novo registro ?", "Confirmação", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            txtCodInstrucao.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (ValidaCampos())
        {  
           // Se a validação estiver OK é implementado o código de INSERT
        }
   }
   #endregion

   #region ALTERA

   else if (StrTextBotao == strConstAltera)
   {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente atualizar as informações ?", "Confirmação", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            txtConteudo.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (ValidaCampos())
        { 
           // Se a validação estiver OK é implementado o código de ALTERA
        }
   }
   #endregion

   Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}

/// <summary>
/// Método que habilita ou desabilita os campos de acordo com o parâmetro de entrada
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pstrTextBtn"></param>
private void HabDes(string pstrTextBtn)
{
    if (strConstInseri == pstrTextBtn) // Inseri
    {
            txtCodInstrucao.Enabled = true;
            txtConteudo.Enabled = true;
            txtCodInstrucao.Focus();

            btnInseri.Enabled = false;
            btnAltera.Enabled = false;
            btnConsulta.Enabled = false;
            btnCancela.Enabled = true;
            btnEfetiva.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (strConstCancela == pstrTextBtn) // Cancela
    {
            txtCodInstrucao.Enabled = false;
            txtConteudo.Enabled = false;

            btnInseri.Enabled = true;
            btnAltera.Enabled = true;
            btnConsulta.Enabled = true;
            btnCancela.Enabled = false;
            btnEfetiva.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (strConstAltera == pstrTextBtn) // Altera
    {
            txtCodInstrucao.Enabled = false;
            txtConteudo.Enabled = true;
            txtConteudo.Focus();

            btnInseri.Enabled = false;
            btnAltera.Enabled = false;
            btnConsulta.Enabled = false;
            btnCancela.Enabled = true;
            btnEfetiva.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (strConstConsulta == pstrTextBtn) // Consulta
    {
            txtCodInstrucao.Enabled = false;
            txtConteudo.Enabled = false;

            btnInseri.Enabled = true;
            btnAltera.Enabled = true;
            btnConsulta.Enabled = true;
            btnCancela.Enabled = true;
            btnEfetiva.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (StrTextBotao == pstrTextBtn) // Efetiva
    {
            txtCodInstrucao.Enabled = false;
            txtConteudo.Enabled = false;

            btnInseri.Enabled = true;
            btnAltera.Enabled = true;
            btnConsulta.Enabled = true;
            btnCancela.Enabled = true;
            btnEfetiva.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Boa noite @Diego Farias estou a tentar testar a forma como você faz mas estou um pouco perdido. O que é HabDes que você utiliza? é que eu tentei colocar e não dá.

Comment: @DiogoSousa, HasDes(), é o método que habilita ou desabilita os campos do formulário. No caso você pode ignorar esse método agora e pensar nele depois que você conseguir fazer funcionar o que você precisa.

Comment: @DiogoSousa, editei minha resposta e acrescentei o código do método HabDes(), para você ter a base de como funciona os exemplos acima. Dentro desse método tenho com componentes do meu formulário. Assim habilito ou desabilito os mesmos de acordo com o botão que foi clicado.

Comment: @DiogoSousa, adicionei a imagem de como é o formulário para você uma ideia melhor de como os botões e os métodos funcionam.